# LEFT OUTER JOIN AND WHERE on joining table

Tags: mysql

To elaborate, I'm selecting fields from item and locations tables. Connection is location_id from items table and id field from locations table. After join I'm doing WHERE statement on city_text field from locations table.

Is this legal action since I'm doing WHERE on field from second table?

```
SELECT uc_items.* ,
       uc_users_store.id AS store_id,
       uc_users_store.store_name,
       uc_users_store.address,
       uc_users_store.work_hours,
       uc_locations.city_text AS city,
       uc_locations.zipcode_text AS zipcode,
       uc_locations.state_text AS STATE,
       uc_locations.country_text AS country
FROM uc_items
LEFT OUTER JOIN uc_users_store ON uc_items.store_id=uc_users_store.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN uc_locations ON uc_users_store.store_location_id=uc_locations.id
WHERE uc_locations.city_text LIKE "%'.$city.'%"
  AND uc_items.iname LIKE "%'.$description.'%"
  AND uc_items.expiration_stamp > '.time().'
ORDER BY uc_items.posting_stamp DESC,
         uc_items.discount DESC
```

Comment: Why not show the SQL?

Comment: It's legal, but using a `WHERE` condition on the `LEFT JOIN` table effectively turns it into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Post your table structure and your query, and we can elaborate or help you through a solution

Comment: I updated with sql, I thought description would be clear enough sorry

Comment: What's your desired result? Do you want rows from `uc_locations` matching the `$city` condition, or non-matching? In that case, you would use `(city_text LIKE '%$city%' OR city_text IS NULL)` so you get the effect of the left join. Looks like someone has addressed that below..

Comment: I want rows from items table matching city from locations table. Connection is uc_items(store_id)->(id)uc_users_store(location_id)->(id)uc_locations(city_text)

Answer (score 0):

It's legal, but might lead to unexpected results if the tested value is `NULL`. However, you could catch these situations by including an `IS NULL` check.

For instance

```
WHERE (col = 'value' OR col IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely legal. However it would be a lot more logical to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` since your `WHERE` statement is concerning the table you are joining to. A pseudo example:

```
SELECT t1.something, t2.somethin FROM first_table t1 INNER JOIN second_table t2 ON t1.some_id = t2.some_id_from_t1 WHERE t2.some_column='something'
```